# Show another activity in a layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application that displays contacts from the contact book. This isnt hard:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, ""+contactId));
startActivity(intent);
```

However, I would like my apps banner to still be showing on the top of the screen. Is there any way to show this new activity as part of my own layout, so I can have my banner and some buttons, and then show the contact in a FrameLayout at the bottom?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: It is impossible. A securityException is always thrown because my app does not have the correct process ID to run that intent within my own activity.